# My function/Fn key isn't working when you as a modifier key

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a USB keyboard and the Fn key works but not when I use it with another key. For Example, F3 works to use the Find feature in my browser and just pressing Fn brings up the right-click menu on the desktop.  but Fn + F3 to raise volume level (which is printed on my keyboard) doesn't work.

Comment: This is more of an [SU](https://superuser.com/) question, possibly related to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/560325/why-dont-logitech-keyboards-media-keys-work).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to update the driver.
also you can checking If the Function Keys are Locked or try Pressing the F11 or F12 Keys
[What if function keys are not working on my computer?](https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/fix-function-keys-not-working/)